# Can I have a Linux based Server which handles roaming profiles for Windows and Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, windows, mac-osx, samba, roaming-profile

Is it possible to have roaming profiles for Windows, and portable home directories for Mac OS X be served up from a Linux Server ?

ie: 1 home directory for a mixed environment.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, though its probably too time-consuming a task for a home setup.

- You'll want to set up your Linux box as a Samba Domain Controller Using OpenLDAP for authentication.
- set up your shares and user's home drives and profiles in smb.conf and in ldap

*/ - for apple connectivity - */
- Add in the apple schema to your ldap (you'll need to disable schema checking in slapd.conf = schemacheck off)
- Configure your mac clients to use your openldap server as a network account server (different in 10.6)
- in ldap, add the objectclass "apple-user" to you user accounts and the attributes "apple-user-homeDirectory" and "apple-user-homeurl" pointing to the samba address of your user's home directories.

eg: 
apple-user-homeDirectory:
/Network/Servers/192.168.1.10/homes/bob

apple-user-homeurl:
smb://192.168.1.10/homes/

useful links:
http://www.howtoforge.com/openldap-samba-domain-controller-ubuntu7.10
http://www.spack.org/wiki/AppleOsxIntegrationWithOpenLdap

Comment: @_ande_turner_ upvoted on your behalf :-)

Comment: Another +1 because it seemed to be a good answer and welcome to the group...hopefully you'll soon get enough rep to upvote answers :-)